# My Audio Is Changing The Start

Tags: audio

I have an audio file, and am trying to animate according to (very precise) it, but it isn't working bc it is starting at different positions according tp where I play it. for example, if I am on keyframe 1, a part in the audio would start at keyframe 100, but if I start at keyframe 50, the same part would be at 120 or 130 keyframe.

Comment: You could provide a minimal representative version of the file on https://blend-exchange.com/ , following the instructions there, packing a small audio file showing the error into your .blend. Then people might have a chance of figuring out what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen when the audio and the animation have different start times or frame rates.

To fix this issue, you will need to make sure that the audio and the animation are synchronized at the same starting frame. Here's how you can do this:

- Open your Blender project and select the object you want to animate.
- Go to the frame where you want the animation to start and set a keyframe for the object's position or rotation.
- Import your audio file into Blender by going to the "Video Editing" workspace and dragging the audio file into the timeline.
- Go to the frame where the audio should start and set a keyframe for the audio's volume.
- Scrub through the timeline and adjust the audio's starting frame until the audio and the animation are synchronized. You can do this by adjusting the audio's starting frame in the timeline or by adjusting the animation's starting frame until the keyframes line up with the audio peaks.
- Once the audio and the animation are synchronized, you should be able to animate the object based on the audio using keyframes that correspond to the peaks and valleys in the audio waveform.